# How to calculate total production time

Tags: anylogic

I've been working on a production model with 2 sources 2 service and 1 assembler as shown below. I was trying to calculate the total time of the production line but it is not possible to put a TimeMeasureStart at the end of the first source and a TimeMeasureEnd block at the end of the Assembler block due to different types of agents, so:

1. What should I do to calculate the total time?

[[image]]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please split your question into two separate questions, this not only makes it easier to answer but also easier for future users with similar questions to find them ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem makes sense. Imagine you are assembling a product with an agent from the `s_caps` source that was produced at time 12 and with an agent from the `s_int_element` source that was produced at time 15. They get assembled at time 20, what is the production time?
Do you use the part with the earliest or that latest creation time?
Or do you add the time each part was in production separately?

You will need to solve this even if you take my suggestion below?

One option is to have a variable inside your two agents and save the creation time for each when they are created as follows

[image]

Now when they enter the assembly block you can either store the time they were created into a list, or perhaps take the average or take the latest (max) or earliest (min) production time.

[image]

In the screenshot, I am taking the min time (thus the earliest time) and I am also saving the creation time to a list of double.
You probably need to implement one of the options, not both

And then when the new agent gets assembled and destroyed you can save the production time as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was not wrong about what exactly  I wanted to calculate (was average total fabrication time btw, no production time). Your idea helped me a lot, I created variables for each delay time. I got the average of those 3 variables and aggregated them.

Comment: That is great news @AndrésLeón. If you found my answer helpful remember to accept it. Also please split your second question into a new question, or if it is not relevant anymore delete it. You can read more about asking good questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask